# difference between E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE and E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE

Tags: php

What is the difference between `E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE` and `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` ?

As I understand they both exclude error reporting of `E_NOTICE` level. But in `PHP.ini` the form `&~` is used, while I've seen in many places the form `^` is mentioned.

Comment: php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

Comment: @djot That's not the question.

Comment: what OP actually needs to know: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a difference between `^` and `&~`, but in this case there is no difference.

`^` means XOR, so bits that are set in either the left operand or the right operand but not both are set in the result. `&~` means AND NOT, so bits that are set in  the left operand but not in the right operand are set in the result.

If we looked at the following numbers, there would be a difference:

```
$a = 0b1010; // decimal 10
$b = 0b0001; // decimal 1
```

`$a ^ $b` results in `0b1011` (decimal 11) whereas `$a & ~$b` results in `0b1010` (decimal 10).

However, `E_ALL` is effectively `0b11111111` (i.e. all the bits are set; it's actually rather more than 8 bits). So XOR is effectively the same as AND NOT.

```
$a = 0b11111111; // decimal 255
$b = 0b00000100; // decimal 4
```

`$a ^ $b` gives `0b11111011` (decimal 251), as does `$a & ~$b`.

Comment: Nice. Was about to write this, but you beat me to it :)

Comment: so if I want to exclude a particular bit from say `$a` without being sure whether it's set in the `$a` I'd need to use `AND NOT` operators, correct?

Comment: @Maximus Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

The first notation is a XOR between `E_ALL` and `E_NOTICE`. The second notation is a bitwise `AND` with a negation operator applied to `E_NOTICE`. The two conditions are technically not equivalent, since the first `XOR` can be rewritten as `((E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE) | (~E_ALL & E_NOTICE))`.

Reference: [php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

*EDIT for completeness:* as Jack and lonesomeday pointed out, since E_ALL has all the relevant bits set to 1, you are in the special case in which the two conditions are equivalent.

Comment: The second part of the xor rewrite is redundant if all bits of the first operand are 1 :)